# Nine Point Circle - Geometric proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have attempted to prove the following statement but I would like to be sure that my proof is correct.

> "All triangles which have the same orthocenter and the same circumscribed circle also have the same nine point circle."

So I went about my proof this way:
1) Since the center of the nine point circle is the midpoint of the straight line which joins the orthocenter and the circumcenter of a triangle, these triangles that have the same orthocenter and circumscribed circle also have the same center for the nine point circle.

2) Since the radius of the nine point circle is half the radius of the circumcircle, then all triangles which have the same circumcircle must also have equal radii of the nine point circle.

SO in all of these triangles the radius and center of the nine point circle are the same and so their nine point circle must be the same.

If it is not a sufficient proof, where should I improve...

Comment: Same center, same radius, same circles, your proof is perfectly fine.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio amazing! Thank you!